# PHP Detect Litespeed

Tags: php, litespeed

I just did a server migration and asked the host to explicitly *not* install Litespeed.

After discovering things not working I found Litespeed listed in the **SAPI Modules** of `phpinfo()`.

On my debug page I list various import bits of information to ensure that my server's configuration is correct and I need to ensure that Litespeed is *not* installed on the server before migrating clients.

How do I detect Litespeed is installed on a server using PHP?

Comment: you can check your response header to see what is the server header , and for PHP , it might be this https://www.cloudlinux.com/mod-lsapi

Comment: @qtwrk No, I need PHP to know this, not the client.

Answer (score 1):

On my local server the substring count is 1 (listed though not loaded?) while on the live it's 2. This *technically* works:

```
<?php
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$php_info = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();

echo strpos($php_info, 'litespeed');
echo '<br />';
echo substr_count($php_info, 'litespeed');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$output = shell_exec('cat /usr/local/lsws/VERSION');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```